# Why is Google returning answers from SO for keywords found in ads?

Tags: bug, search, google

I just searched Google for:

> c# get object property by name ios

Google returned this result: [How to get property name and its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315073/how-to-get-property-name-and-its-value)

Searching that page for iOS turns up nothing. But the search summary shows:

> C# How can I get the value of a string property via Reflection? public
>   class myClass { public .... Lead iOS Developer. After School

This looks to me like the Careers ad was showing "Lead iOS Developer" when the Google bot found this answer. Shouldn't ad content be excluded from the content that indexes the Q&A pages?

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow search returns no results, but Google search returns 2,000?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286485)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a problem for *Google* to fix, not for Stack Overflow.

Pages on Stack Overflow are correctly marked up using [Schema.org mark-up](https://schema.org/QAPage), giving Google all the information needed to know what parts of the page are important:

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
        <h1 itemprop="name">Question title</h1>
        <div ... itemprop="text">Question body</div>

        <div ... itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
            <div ... itemprop="text">Answer body</div>
        </div>
        <!-- multiple answers possible -->
    </div>
</html>
```

But if Google wants to include the advertisement copy in their search results *anyway*, then that's their responsibility and we cannot do anything to prevent them, short of loading advertisement copy entirely asynchronous (which means a possible performance hit) or serving Google alternative content (which they frown upon).