# What progress has been made recently toward improving Stack Overflow search results?

Tags: feature-request, search

Originally I was going to ask about how Stack Overflow search could be improved. Because it so rarely returns the results that I want, I don't use it much. The exceptions are:

1. searching for `myUserName + my topic` to refer back to some of my old answers
2. checking for obvious duplicates before I post a question.

However, before I asked my question, I saw (thanks to Stack Overflow search) that [a similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286485/stack-overflow-search-returns-no-results-but-google-search-returns-2-000) had already been asked. This question is from last February and the original [feedback request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277584/feedback-requested-search-engine-usage) is from last year.

How are things progressing and changing recently related to improving search results? What was the decision about the given feedback?

Comment: Even the `user:me + keywords` doesn't always work, especially when the exact search terms only appeared in code.

Comment: Could you add some concrete examples with search terms and expected top answers?

Comment: My original question was going to be about a concrete example, but that changed when I saw the other question I linked to above. If you click the feedback request link above, you can see many ideas that people gave for and against changing how SO search works. My current question here is what (if anything) has been (or is being) implemented from those suggestions.

Comment: Just use Google with "site:stackoverflow.com" like everybody else ;) - That said, I'd love to be able to use real SO search with "is:", "[tags]" and other keywords.

Comment: Search always sucks on most any system, its because it is not easy...Companies fail to see this.  I worked at a place that dealt with a ton of data..a CRM type system.  When we built search the spec from the end users was "Make it work like google"..O what a simple task...behind the scenes google has invested not only time but very elaborate algorithms, a lot of data scientists, a lot and I mean a lot of professors working on algorithms, a ton of lessons learned and bug fixes and the ability to have some of the best programmers work on the search.  Its not a job for one person!

Comment: @JonH I'm the project manager, if I get you an extra person then how long would it take?

Comment: @TomHart That was funny....again search is not easy.  I cant remember how many people worked on search on SO, I think it was just Nick Carver.  But that is NOT enough people to make search useable.

Comment: I think search is one of those things that is about constant improvements. It's not a case of get it right first time and it will always be good

Comment: There's almost no way to make a general search that would be more functional than vhu's suggestion (and, as a suggestion, I find Google to be a *very* effective way to search SO). There may, however, be ways to make a few much more narrow search features that are focused on a specific SO-navigation problem and are effective at solving that problem *only* - perhaps focusing only on "related" or "possible duplicate" as a search area, or "mistagged", etc. Even so, as pointed out by JonH, search is not easy, and may not be worth the effort.

Comment: @TomHart sort of... even minor improvements could be beyond someone who hasn't studied it at a high academic level (or spent years dealing with the problem and have absorbed the same principles).

Comment: Apparently search is a feature that doesn't get much attention. Perhaps there is one developer working on it, but they don't seem to be getting team support. Luckily in order to make content easier to find there will be a whole new feature called Documentation. Search implementation for content in Documentation will naturally be delayed in the same way SO search is. Ironic that the new features are supposed to help work with problems developers face while their inception seems to already be causing their own developers problems.

Comment: Luckily, a new team feature is being made that will help the team help this one developer with search. However, that will be delayed until the new feature Teams is implemented. Naturally finding the search feature will be delayed until the SO search feature is improved, so it may not even be obvious that the Team needs to improve search.

Comment: Most people seem to use Google to search SO. What if we replaced the SO search box with the [Google Custom Search Engine](https://cse.google.com/cse/)? That would save the pain of typing `site:stackoverflow.com` every time.

Comment: @Suragch There is my [suggestion to allow use of regex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313314/add-ability-to-craft-regex-expressions-for-the-search-bar) over on the main Meta.