# Search does not bring back hits though distinct, non-prominant usage

Tags: feature-request, search

If I use the search bar for "CreateClientBuffer" [I get no results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CreateClientBuffer) (as of writing).

That phrase is used on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23773786/295686) and [other places](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+CreateClientBuffer).

Why does the search not return that page?

This has been [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308398/295686) but here is an example as the comments mention.

Comment: Interestingly, searching for [WebSocket.CreateClientBuffer](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WebSocket.CreateClientBuffer) *does* return results.