# Search field is cleared by new question notification

Tags: bug, new-nav

Not sure if it's a `new-nav`.

When typing something into search field (on top, to the right from `help`) as soon as bar

```
                                1 new question
```

appears (or is updated with more questions) then the search field is **cleared**.

---

To example was

```
[C#]
```

I start typing

```
[C#] something important I am trying to search for
```

and then BAM (in the middle of typing), it's empty

```
[C#]
```

Answer (score -1):

After more than one year the bug still exists and there is no comment from Stack Overflow. So, the solution is to avoid SO search altogether and use google or other external search engines. It seems you will also get [better](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350767/search-not-finding-methods-in-code-searched-for-by-name) [results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308398/what-progress-has-been-made-recently-toward-improving-stack-overflow-search-resu) that way.

<sup>Sorry for the "ranty" tone, I wrote this as an attempt to draw some attention to this bug.</sup>