# Search not finding methods in code searched for by name

Tags: bug, search

I was searching for a specific topic using the keyword "UseOAuthAuthentication":
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=useoauthauthentication

Unfortunately, the results did not include 
[Integrating ASP.NET code to Active Directory or LDAP after deploying on Bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236090/integrating-asp-net-code-to-active-directory-or-ldap-after-deploying-on-bluemix), which contains a line of code:

```
app.UseOAuthAuthentication(options);
```

I tried adding "Bluemix" to the search (which appears in the title), but SO's search still can't find it:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UseOAuthAuthentication+bluemix

Not even `code:` helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bluemix+code%3AUseOAuthAuthentication

Bing ranks it second though:
https://www.bing.com/search?q=useoauthauthentication+bluemix

If you were to search for [`*UseOAuthAuthentication`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=*UseOAuthAuthentication+bluemix) or [`*.UseOAuthAuthentication`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=*.UseOAuthAuthentication+bluemix), it shows up, but this seems counter-intuitive to how people would try to use search.

I guess I won't use SO's own search for a while...

Comment: I have a hard time searching SO as well.  I typically just use google

Comment: "Bing ranks it second though:" Bing .. What is it? Wait a second Bing! Dw!

Comment: Whats's really fun is if you search the first line of the answer it finds it.  My guess is since that line of code is at the end of a longish answer it is not actually getting included in data to search.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: Because that string is found in a code block, you need to specify an additional search parameter.  Try the using the [`code:"searchTerm"` syntax](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331866/4320665).  Notice the required quotes for the `code` syntax.

Comment: @DragandDrop: it's a quite good search engine in case you don't want to get up one day and see that you **must** use Google.

Comment: @ÁkosSzegő And they pay you...

Comment: @ryanyuyu [except that doesn't show that particular question either](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22UseOAuthAuthentication%22)

Comment: If search was improved the number of duplicate questions should go down. I've asked a question that was (correctly) closed as a dupe and I couldn't figure out why the search terms I had tried before asking hadn't found it.

Comment: When searching for a method, you need to prepend `*.` to the method (or just `*`). In this case, it means searching for [`*.UseOAuthAuthentication`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=*.UseOAuthAuthentication), which shows the answer you desire as the fourth result, when sorted by votes. Thus, the issue you are encountering is that the search engine does not consider periods to separate searchable words. If you wanted it with Bluemix, you could search for [`*.UseOAuthAuthentication bluemix`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=*.UseOAuthAuthentication+bluemix).

Comment: @Makyen: thanks for the insight. IMHO this should be included as a remark in search results view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: @Carrosive, Yes, the search help page mentions wildcards. In English, and programming, it's reasonable to assume a `.` separates search terms. My first assumption would be that it both does and doesn't (i.e. that both separated and unseparated would be considered searchable words). Not separating on `.` *forces* you to search for the entire reference, when people generally want uses of the method, not the method of a specific variable.  IMO, the issue is that the search help page doesn't explicitly state that `.` does not separate words, that you *must* search for the entire reference.

Comment: Google **site:stackoverflow.com UseOAuthAuthentication bluemix** and it will be the second one down (third if you count the ad).

Answer (score 7):

[I asked about search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308398/what-progress-has-been-made-recently-toward-improving-stack-overflow-search-resu) a couple years ago, but there doesn't seem to have been much progress. I'm sure it is a complex and time consuming task to make an effective search engine. It would be worth the effort, though, I believe. In addition to improving the general user experience, it would also lower the number of duplicates ([as @samgag commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350767/search-seems-to-have-big-problems?cb=1#comment482369_350767)).

If improving the in-house search is not feasible in the short term, I recommend replacing it with a Google (or Bing) powered search. This wouldn't look quite as seamless as the in-house approach, but it would save the step of having to go to another page and type in `site:stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: Thanks! If I mark this as an answer, will this code search issue be still considered for fixing in the next(?) release ?

Comment: @ÁkosSzegő, my "answer" does not really answer the problem. It is more of an extended comment/feature request. If an SO employer adds an answer saying that they are working on it, you can accept their answer. Accepting an answer or not does not influence whether they consider fixing a bug. As I understand it, including the `bug` tag in your question puts it in some sort of bug queue.