# Search box shows no results but Ask question does

Tags: feature-request, search

If I type keywords on the Stack Overflow search box I often get 0 results. However, using the exact same search term as a title in a question will show several similar questions that would be suitable results for me.

Is there a way to get the same "results" in the search box? I know there are related questions such as the [difference with search engines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286485/stack-overflow-search-returns-no-results-but-google-search-returns-2-000) (I tend to use search engines mostly too) and [future improvements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277584/feedback-requested-search-engine-usage) to search. But I'm not asking for any of those, just the ability to get the same results as in "Ask a question" without having to use this workaround. Not sure if this should be a feature request, or if there's already a way to do this. Thanks.

There is a very [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268318/why-is-the-this-question-might-exist-search-better-than-the-normal-search) noted in the comments (thank you!), but with one fundamental difference: I got **0 results**. The related question shows several results. *Update: just tried the example in the other question and also got 0 results, so I guess search has changed since then?*

One recent example I have is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937320/gcp-gce-f1-micro-not-free) I had seen yesterday and wanted to find again. If I type something like "gcp e2-micro free shows monthly estimate" I get: *"We couldn't find anything for **gcp e2-micro free shows monthly estimate**. Try different or less specific keywords."* Putting the same text in *Ask Question* showed me what I was looking for in the second result under *similar questions*.

I cannot remember other examples now but I am certain that this is not the first time it happened to me.

Comment: Have you got some good examples?

Comment: Related: [Why is the "this question might exist" search better than the normal search?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268318/215552)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, updated question to address both.

Comment: @anastaciu I called it "Related" because this question is a [feature-request] and that one is a [discussion]. Seems kind of odd to close a request for a new feature as a dupe for a discussion about the crappiness of existing features, no?

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, I missed that detail, I'm kind of new on meta, thanks for the heads up.